# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException exception is thrown while using move to element even when element is in view port

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using a method to hover on an element and the select a value from dropdown which appears after hovering. the same element and same method is used in two different test cases. This works perfectly fine in one test case and throws exception in another test case.

i tried using scrolling to the element using javascript, also tried separating the actions, but it did not work.

```
    WebElement bpardingPointFilterNew=  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#bpliner"));
        action.moveToElement(bpardingPointFilterNew).click(bpardingPointFilterNew).perform();
    //  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",bpardingPointFilterNew);
    //  action.click(bpardingPointFilterNew).perform();
    //  bpardingPointFilterNew.click();

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the markup for the page, and maybe a couple of the preceding automation actions too.  When you inspect this element in the browser, what location is showing?

Comment: Hi,Below is the sample html````Hi, Below is the html.````<div class="navSection row topTabLayer"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navSection_link" id="bpliner"> <span class="dib"><i class="fl icon-boarding ico22 lh1-2 greyDr"></i><span class="fl pad5 hidden-xs">Boarding Point</span><i class="icon-arrow-down ico10 lh1-2 fl downArrFilter hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i></span> </a>
         <ul class="navSection_secondary hoverEffect col-md-2 col-sm-2" id="bpopcontr">
            <li class="onward"></div>````

Comment: But how come it's working fine in one test case and not in another one?

Comment: initializing Actions  in method resolved my issue.